# Super simple query takes 39 seconds to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My DB has about 150K `DocumentNames` records and all I am doing is a simple join with `NameTypes`. NameTypeID is a foreign key in DocumentNames.

This is my query:

```
With cte as 
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (Order By nm.Name asc ) 
    peta_rn,    
    dn.DocumentNameID,
    dn.DocumentID  
    From DocumentNames dn

    Left Join NameTypes nm On dn.NameTypeID = nm.NameTypeID
) 
Select * from cte Where peta_rn >= 10000 And peta_rn <= 10050
```

This is the screenshot:

[image]

The sort takes 90% cost. I am totally confused what should I do at this point. I want to bang my head but I can't as there are other people around. Please suggest what should I do?

Comment: If you arrange your `NameTypes` in alphabetical order you wouldn't need the join. You could just order by `NameTypeID`.

Comment: Is the left join necessary? Can it be changed to an inner join? If so, you might create an indexed view on both tables and sacrifice some speed for insert/update/deletes to selects.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: NameTypeID is a nullable column hence I need Left Join.

Comment: I would Denormalise `Name` into your `DocumentNames` table and create an ordered index on it. Some things are not easily fixable by just altering a query.

Comment: Are you indexing any of the fields?

Comment: @Mark: ClusteredIndex is on DocumentNameID for DocumentNames and NameTypeID on NameTypes and nonclustered index on Name in NameTypes and index on NameTypeID in DocumentNames.

Comment: @Jack - How important then is it to show those records first where the nametype is unknown? Besides, the ROW_NUMBER ORDER BY solution is [not deterministic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919325/undetermined-sort-order-when-using-row-number-over-decimal-column-with-ties) for those NULL values so the resulting order might vary from run to run.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: It is not important. It is the result of user performing this action. I have columns in my asp.net gridview and when user clicks on NameType, I need to sort by that column. Yes I understand your point about Row_Number Order By. I can fix that easily but main issue is how to bring down the query response time.

Comment: Does a clustered index on nm.Name remove your sort and improve response time?

Comment: @ElectricLlama: Unfortunately, no. It doesn't. I remove clustered index on NameTypeID and put it on Name and yet the same results. I guess I should forget optimizing this and penalize the user for his own actions.

Comment: Implementing what @Filip De Vos suggested would be my first choice then but it has its risk *(falling out of sync)*. Another option might be to create a clustered indexed view on those records that **do** have a name *(hello inner join)* and union those results with the ones that don't have a name. That way, the row_number on the indexed view can use, well, an index <g>.

Comment: Does it change the query plan when you change the clustered index? I guess not.

Comment: The index on `nm.Name` isn't as useful as it might be, because of the outer join. Name may be NULL in the output of the CTE. And this also means `ROW_NUMBER()` isn't going to be consistent from one run to the next, because the records that don't match `NameTypes` will come in random order. (For that matter, without a secondary sort column, the records that _do_ match will also come in random order, within blocks!) So, I suggest that something is amiss with the whole point of `ROW_NUMBER()`—maybe it would be better to step back and ask yourself (and us) what this query is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Andrew: The query is what it *looks* it is trying to accomplish. Can the problem you just described not be solved by doing a Order by again  after the With clause is over?

Comment: It could be. My point is that ROW_NUMBER is completely arbitrary within groups where Name is constant. There isn't any way to go back from the ROW_NUMBER to anything in the original tables. I can't see what use it has in the final output. If you can explain that, it might be possible to rewrite the query, perhaps even without a CTE.

Comment: Okay for now, let's do a IsNull so if it's null we use '' in Order By. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but **the entire query doesn't make sense** except as an arbitrary statement in SQL. The ROW_NUMBER has no meaning in the real world. You could, for example, move the `WHERE` on `peta_rn` into the CTE (meaning, no CTE, just one query), and you would have the same results modulo the unspecified random behavior of records that have the same `nm.Name`, and it would probably run faster. There is a forest/tree problem here.

Comment: @Andrew: I am not trying to be rude either but it looks you are unnecessarily going on a different agenda instead of trying to solve the problem. This is the query that I was trying to write: "Sort by Name and fetch those records lying between 10000 and 100050". Can't explain any better than that. If this doesn't make sense to you, I am sorry. By the way your assumption of no CTE just one query is wrong. It doesn't have any effect on performance and makes no difference. The real problem is Sort taking up 90% of cost. I hope you saw the query execution plan.

Comment: Why do you need to get records "lying between 10000 and 10050" when they are going to be inconsistent between query runs due to the reasons @AndrewLazarus stated? Are you trying to do paging in the web page's data grid, and you forgot to mention that?

Comment: @HardCode, well I asked him what he was trying to accomplish (e.g., paging), but he's too smart to fall into my clever trap. Or whatever. He's fixated on optimizing a probably-unnecessary sort, outputting _random_ row numbers. I think I'll bookmark this for Tunnel Vision 101.

Comment: @HardCode: Yes, I am paginating in a web page's data grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it worth, here is [some SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42fee/11) to test any syntax.

By far the simplest approach is to enusre that the `NameTypes` are inserted in `Name` order, and therefore, that the `NameTypeID`s are assigned alphabetically.

In this situation there is no need to join to the `NameTypes` table. You can just do,

```
WITH [CTE] AS
(
SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [NameTypeID] ASC) [PetaRN],    
            [DocumentNameID],
            [DocumentID]
    FROM
            [DocumentNames]
) 
SELECT
            [PetaRN],
            [DocumentNameID],
            [DocumentID]
    FROM
            [CTE]
    WHERE
            [PetaRN] BETWEEN 10000 AND 10050
    ORDER BY
            [PetaRN] ASC;
```

---

How about

```
WITH [CTE] AS
(
SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [NameTypeID] ASC) [PetaRN],    
            [DocumentNameID],
            [DocumentID]
    FROM
            [DocumentNames]
) 
SELECT TOP 50
            [PetaRN],
            [DocumentNameID],
            [DocumentID]
    FROM
            [CTE]
    WHERE
            [PetaRN] >= 10000
    ORDER BY
            [PetaRN] ASC;
```

---

When testing large datasets on SQL 2005 I've noticed that CTE's don't perform well for large result sets, this may be related to resource availability on the server. A counter intuitive use of temporary tables may turn out to be faster. This also allows you to index the row number allowing quick page selection however, this must be offset against the cost of insertion. Try it and see.

```
CREATE TABLE #Peta
(
    [PetaRN] BigInt NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_Peta] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [DocumentNameID] Int NOT NULL,
    [DocumentID] Int NOT NULL
);

INSERT #Peta
SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [NameTypeID] ASC) [PetaRN],    
            [DocumentNameID],
            [DocumentID]
    FROM
            [DocumentNames];

SELECT TOP 50
            [PetaRN],
            [DocumentNameID],
            [DocumentID]
    FROM
            #Peta
    WHERE
            [PetaRN] >= 10000
    ORDER BY
            [PetaRN] ASC;


DROP TABLE #Peta;
```

Comment: I would love to do that however that still doesn't solve the problem. It still takes 50 seconds with clustered index on NameTypeID

Comment: @Jack, are most of NameTypeID's NULL?

Answer (score 3):

If, for some arbitrary reason (like a job interview), you need to optimize a query like this, try a `UNION`.

[**Corrected** to recognize alias column]

```
With cte as 
(
  Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (Order By nm.Name asc ) AS
  peta_rn,    
  dn.DocumentNameID,
  dn.DocumentID  
  From DocumentNames dn

  INNER Join NameTypes nm On dn.NameTypeID = nm.NameTypeID /* note change */
),  
cte2 as 
(
  Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  () AS /* yes, this is random */
  peta_rn,    
  dn.DocumentNameID,
  dn.DocumentID  
  From DocumentNames dn

  WHERE dn.NameTypeID  NOT IN SELECT (nm.NameTypeID FROM NameTypes nm)
) 

Select * from cte Where peta_rn >= 10000 And peta_rn <= 10050

UNION

Select * from cte2 Where peta_rn >= 10000 And peta_rn <= 10050
```

I've never done a `UNION` with CTEs, so you may need some extra parentheses to make this legal. Also an `ORDER BY` for the entire result. I'll leave that as an exercise.

The point is that the `INNER JOIN` will be able to use the index on `nm.Name`, while the second clause will be able to do an indexed anti-semijoin. Two indexed queries should be much faster than one unindexed query.

Comment: Nice. You've implemented and mentioned the same solutions/problems I did in comments. +1 if you can solve the between 10000 and 10050 problem. As is, this will return 100 records. 50 random NULL values and 50 names.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, sorry, I skipped over your comment, which I have now upvoted. Which table is `peta_rn` in? (Although, as you can see from the comment flame war, there is something brain-damaged about the entire setup, which is what happens when you beat your head against a wall.) Perhaps you can just move the `WHERE` into the CTEs. Why the filter is after the CTE is unclear to me, because the entire operation is unclear.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: I also see on your profile reference to **the exact issue we have here**: The XY Problem! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: OP is trying to page through the results but as you (and I) already said, the current solution is flawed and so will be other solutions. +1 on effort though.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers. Thank you, just 23,000 more and I will catch up to you. For re-sorting an existing page without regard to the global sort, wouldn't it just be best to do it client-side in the UI widget? Skip the trip to the DB completely?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: **/* note comma missing in OP */** - just to clarify, it isn't missing. It is aliased as peta_rn.

Comment: @Jack. Thanks, I get it now. (I tend to forget that Postgres, my usual DB, fails to conform to SQL by requiring `AS`)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - That would mean getting *everything* to the client. Don't sweat about the rep, I've seen many catch up and more.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you could try:

1. Make the clustered index start with Name... not very efficient to have a wide clustered index but give it a go and see if it stops the sort occuring
2. Permanently create a column which has the order number in it. This depends on how often your table is updated.

Please post your table and index definitions.

Comment: ClusteredIndex is on DocumentNameID for DocumentNames and NameTypeID on NameTypes.

Comment: So maybe try creating a clustered index on nm.Name instead and see if it removes your sort.... it might have other bad consequences but you have to start somewhere.